# Javascript, finding first significant figure (values ranging from 87.352 to 0.0002432)

Tags: javascript, gps, coordinates

I have created a GPS system using coordinates.

I have found the highest and lowest longitude and latitude coordinates using this function:

```
var maxLng = 0;
var maxLat = 0;
  var minLng = 180;
  var minLat = 180;
  for(var i=0; i<coordinates.length; i++)
  {

    //get max coordinates (the +90 is to remove negative numbers)
    if (coordinates[i][0]+90 > maxLat)
    {
      maxLat = coordinates[i][0] + 90;
    }

    if (coordinates[i][1]+90 > maxLng)
    {
      maxLng = coordinates[i][1]+ 90;
    }

    //get min coordinates
    if (coordinates[i][0]+90 < minLat)
    {
      minLat = coordinates[i][0] + 90;
    }

    if (coordinates[i][1]+90 < minLng)
    {
      minLng = coordinates[i][1] + 90;
    }
  }

  console.log(maxLat, maxLng,minLat, minLng);

  //calculate distance between max and min points
  var lngDistance = maxLng - minLng;
  var latDistance = maxLat - minLat;

  console.log(lngDistance, latDistance);
```

This outputs the distance between the 2 furthest apart longitude and latitude points, which I then plan to use to create a basic 2d map looking like this:

[image]

I need to convert the points, they can be a range of value such as:

0.0009321
19.332
1.9432123
0.0013432423
0.23432423
0.000034324

I want to basically convert all the numbers to 2 significant figures in front of the decimal point and store the result in the array stating how many shifts I have used.

I would want the output to be something like this (original number, converted number, shifts used):

```
[0.0009321, 93.21, 4]
[19.332, 19.332, 0]
[1.9432123, 19.432123, 1]
[0.0013432423, 13.432423, 3]
...
```

I am thinking find the first significant figure then count how far away from the decimal point this is. I found a few posts about using REGEX to do this, but I have never used REGEX before.

Can anybody give me some pointers?

Cheers.

Comment: Regex is the wrong tool to convert number to 2 significant figures

Comment: Hmmm ok thanks nhahtdh, can you think of any tools that may help me solve this? Been baffled by it for hours!

Comment: What is the expected result for the example you are having? 0 19 2 0 0 0? Or 0.00093 19 1.9 0.0013 0.23 0.000034?

Comment: I have edited the question, to show what I want to output

Comment: Check this out: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toPrecision After you use that, I think you can split at `e` and process the output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That was a fun one figuring out.

Made a basic function for you, and as far as I can see it works.

```
function change(data){
    var ret=new Array();
    for(var i=0,len=data.length;i<len;i++){
        // make string from number, remove the dot
        var st=(''+data[i]).replace('.','');
        //remove leading zero's from string
        var no_zero=st.replace(/^0+/,'');
        //make value
        var val=parseInt(no_zero)/(Math.pow(10,no_zero.length-2));
        //calculate amount of steps
        var steps=Math.round(Math.log(Math.round(val/data[i]))/Math.log(10));

        //correction for floating point
        if(data[i]<0.01)steps--;

        ret.push([data[i],val,steps]);
    }
    return ret;
}
```

And [a working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/79yoryjL/)